# Limit involving a sequence of non-integrable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space. Moreover, let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables that are not integrable. Next, fix $K>0$ and set $C_n:=\{|X_n| \geq nK\}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Do we have $$P\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty} C_n \right)=1?$$

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is a non0negative random variable then $$EY\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\{Y\geq n\}$$: $$EY=\sum EYI_{n\leq Y <n+1}\geq \sum (n+1)P\{n\leq Y <n+1\}\leq \sum 2nP\{n\leq Y <n+1\}$$. Now $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\{Y\geq n\}=\sum_n \sum_{j=n}^{\infty} P\{j\leq Y <j+1\}=\sum_j \sum_{n=1}^{j} P\{j\leq Y <j+1\}$. We have proved that this last quantity is $ \geq \frac 1 2EY$. Now we apply this to the given situation. $E|X_1|=\infty$ implies $\frac {E|X_1|} K=\infty$ which implies $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\{|X_1|\geq nK\}=\infty$. Now apply Borel - Cantelli Lemma. We get $P\{\limsup |X_n|\geq nK\}=1$.

Comment: Surely. If $X_n$'s are independent then the events $X_n^{-1}(E)$ are independent for any Borel set $E$.

Comment: I think we need $EY\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(Y\geq n)}$.

Comment: @ShaqAttack1337 You are right. Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my proof.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{j} 1 =j$ so $\sum P\{Y\geq n\} =\sum_j jP\{j \leq Y <j+1\}$.